# How would I scan an integer value followed by a character using scanf in C

Tags: c, char, text-files, scanf, getchar

So I am trying to scan 91h from a text file. So far I have tried using getchar and also scanf but neither of them scans the entire 91h to a declared string. 
Is there a trick I am missing here?

Comment: Pls elaborate with some code snippet

Comment: Are you just trying to read "91h" into a string buffer? Or "91" into a variable and then "h" into another variable?

Comment: "scan the entire 91h to a declared string." If the input line is `91h` what is wrong with using `char int_char[20]; scanf("%19s", int_char)`?

Comment: What is the type of variable for the destination?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int x3 = 0;
    int x4 = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%xh %xh %xh %xh", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4);

    printf("x1: %x, x2: %x, x3: %x, x4: %x\n", x1, x2, x3, x4);
}
```

Test data in file test.txt:

```
91h 82h 93h 94h
91h 82h 93h 94h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply reading them into a buffer:

```
char buff[128];
(f)scanf(file, "%s", buff);
```

If you are reading them into 2 separate variables:

```
int num;
char var;
(f)scanf("%2d%c", &num, &var);
```

Comment: This won't work for with, for example `9Ah`, although the intent of the question is unclear.

Comment: With his input it's fine.  But what does he want?